# myfaces 2.1.17 - f:viewParam setter being called on commandlink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, viewparams

In JSF2.0, when commandlink is pressed (posted), should the f:viewParam setter be called again?  In myfaces 2.0, it does not call the viewParam setter again, but in myfaces 2.1, it is.  Is this correct?  Is there a way to globally disable it?

Comment: @Balus, I found that dup post that you mentioned.  I was just wonder if this is new in jsf2.1.  Because in jsf 1.2, the viewparam setter is not being called on postback.  If it is new in jsf2.1, is there a way to globally set it to not do that.

Comment: `<f:viewParam>` doesn't exist in JSF 1.x. Entire tag is ignored and will likely appear plain vanilla in generated HTML output. It was introduced in JSF 2.0 (for Facelets only and thus not JSP). In JSF 1.x you would need `<managed-property>` or `getRequestParameterMap()` to manually grab request/view parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say jsf 2.0 was not calling viewparam setter on postback, but 2.1 is.

Comment: That must have been an old Myfaces specific bug/oversight.